# How do I generate a 'Hash-Code' for a document or photograph?

Tags: command-line, security, hash

I want to generate a 'Hash-Code' for a document and a photograph.

How do I do this please?

Comment: Is this to ensure no one has doctored the picture or rewritten the document?

Comment: Which hash code is required ? There's many versions as heemayl mentioned in his answer

Comment: Thank you all for the info.  Have now generated 'hash-codes' following your advice.

Answer (score 6):

At first choose the hashing algorithm you want to use. For example, `md5`, `sha256`, `sha384`, `sha512` etc.

A point to note that, unless you are looking at cryptographic usage or where security is more important than complexity, `md5` should be enough for regular file hashing that you want to crosscheck afterwards.

Now, GNU `coreutils` comes with most of the hash generating binaries for common algorithms:

```
% dpkg -L coreutils | grep '[0-9]sum$'
/usr/bin/sha224sum
/usr/bin/sha512sum
/usr/bin/md5sum
/usr/bin/sha1sum
/usr/bin/sha256sum
/usr/bin/sha384sum
```

Now pick the one of your choice, and do the sum e.g. for `md5sum`:

```
md5sum foobar.jpg
```

Replace `foobar.jpg` with the file of your choice to get the hash for that.

Also check the relevant `man` pages e.g. `man md5sum`.